# Spline Spawn in Unreal

Tags: unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint

I'm starting with Unreal Engine and I would like to know if there is a way to instantiate a spline from point A (Caster) to B (receiver) and how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do it by adding a spline component and then set up 2 points on the desired locations like this:

[image: Unreal blueprint as example]

As you can see, there's a way to instantiate it and the only way I can imagine can work is to add 2 points and set up the position as you want.